# Instantiate a ManagedBean (declared as @ManagedProperty) before using inside another ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

I am using a `@ManagedBean`(request scoped) as a `@ManagedProperty` inside another `@ManagedBean`. However the bean(one used as a `@ManagedProperty`) at the time of usage is un-instantiated and therefore leads to `NullPointerException`.

How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're apparently trying to access it in the constructor of the parent bean. This is indeed not possible. The managed properties are injected after construction.

```
ParentBean parentBean = new ParentBean(); // Constructor invoked.
parentBean.setChildBean(new ChildBean()); // Managed property set.
```

The earliest access point is a [`@PostConstruct`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) method. It's invoked after construction **and** managed property (and all other dependency like `@EJB`) injection.

```
@ManagedProperty("#{childBean}")
private ChildBean childBean;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    System.out.println(childBean); // Not null.
}
```